# Android - Custom Home Application Doesn't Appear When Click Home Button

Tags: android, android-studio

I'am using Android Studio and I have developed an Home Application by adding

```
<activity
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance"
            android:stateNotNeeded="true"
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.MONKEY"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

This is working and I am testing my application with run button no problem.
But after run another app from Android Studio the home application stop appearing home button selection screen.(not everytime). This is how I solve my problem

- I create another application
- Move files and codes to new created project.
- Then my code is working with different name

This looks like a bug, I dont know what is that. Is there a way to clear cache data or another simple way to solve the problem or any suggestion?

Comment: can you please explain that sentence _But after run another app from Android Studio the home application stop appearing home button selection screen._ I don't understand your question

Comment: After run another application no any connection with home app (another project), then I try to test my home app project again , home application doesn't appear. When I click home button, "launcher"app working as default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You most likely have a different launcher set as default launcher.

In the settings of your device you should be able to set the default launcher.
Go to applications and look for your current launcher. Clear the default launcher.

If you cleared the default launcher and correctly installed your launcher, it should now ask every time which launcher to launch when you hit the home button.

**Tip: Try it out on different devices and emulators!**